Product of quotient spaces vs. quotient of product spaces
For an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a topological space $X$, form the natural $f^{\ast}$ map from the quotient
space $(X \times X)/\sim'$ to $(X/\sim) \times (X/\sim)$,
where $\sim'$ is the equivalence relation on the product $X \times X$ given by$
(x, y) \sim' (u, v)$ if and only if $x \sim u$ and $y \sim v$.
In other words, $f^{\ast}$ is the map obtained from the map $f = q \times q : X \times X \rightarrow (X/\sim) \times (X/\sim)$ by passing to the quotient, where $q : X \to X/\sim$ is the quotient map associated with $\sim$.
Explicitly, for $(x, y) \in X \times X$, we have
$f^{\ast}([x, y]_{\sim^{\prime}}) = (q(x), q(y)) = ([x]_{\sim}, [y]_{\sim})$,
where $[.\, ,.]_{\sim^{\prime}}$ denotes the equivalence class in $X \times X$ for $\sim^{\prime}$
and $[.]_{\sim}$ denotes the equivalence class in $X$ for $\sim$.
It is well known that $f^{\ast}$ is a bijective continuous map, that $f^{\ast}$ need not be a homeomorphism, and that in some circumstances (by a theorem of Whitehead) $f^{\ast}$ is a homeomorphism.

What is the situation when $X = \mathbb{Q}$, the space of rationals, and $\sim$ collapses the set $\mathbb{Z}$ of integers to a point — that is, $x \sim y$ if and only if $x = y$ or else $x$ and $y$ are both integers? Is $f^{\ast}$ a homeomorhism here?
What is the situation when $X = \mathbb{R}$, the space of reals, and $\sim$ collapses the set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals to a point — that is, $x \sim y$ if and only if $x = y$ or else $x$ and $y$ are both rational? Is $f^{\ast}$ a homeomorhism here?

In each case, the question is (I believe) equivalent to asking whether $f$ is a quotient map.

Somebody had provided an answer. What happened to it?

The answer was deleted 8 days ago by the post author.

Let $Y$ is $\mathbb Z$ in the first case and $\mathbb Q$ in the second case. As I understand the definition of $f^*$, in order to show that it is not open (at $[Y\times Y]$), it suffices to find a neighborhood $U$ of $Y\times Y$ in $X\times X$ such that there exist no neighborhood $V$ of $Y$ with $V\times V\subset U$. For this choose any enumeration $\{y_n\}_{n\in\omega}$ of $Y\times Y$ and put $$U=\bigcup_{n\in\omega} \{x\in X\times X: d(x,y_n)<2^{-n}\},$$ where $d$ is the Euclidean distance on $X\times X$.

Why does that suffice to show that $f^{\ast}$ is not an open map?

@murray Because then it will be shown that $f^*$ is not a homeomorphism.

My question is NOT why does it suffice to show that $f^{\sst}$ is not an open map, but rather why does the condition you give (a neighborhood $U$ of $Y \times Y$, etc) suffice to show that $f^{\ast}$ is not open?

@murray Because, as I understand the definition of $f^$, then $f^([U])$ will contain no neighborhood of $f^*([Y\times Y])$.

I don't understand the definition of $U$: it does not seem to use anywhere the enumeation of $Y \times Y$. Do you mean $U = \bigcup_{n \in \omega} {,x \in X \times X : d(x, y_n) < 1/n,}$?

@murray Yes, of course. Fixed. Sorry for the misprint and thanks for your attention.
